# Add existing database view/table from object explorer to entity diagram

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

I have created a new asp.net 2012 mvc application.  I am moving an existing web forms application over to the mvc model. The web forms application uses linq to sql, but since it's no longer going to be supported, I am going to use linq to entities.

Having never used mvc or linq to entities, I have been reading every article I can find. 
I added the ado.net entity model and generated the diagram from my existing sql server 2005 database.   I was having problems in the .edmx diagram with a relationship so I deleted the view expecting to be able to **drag it back to the diagram**.

I have looked all over on adding an existing database view/table to a diagram with no luck. I don't want to regenerate it, I spent a lot of time modifying relationships etc. in the current Diagram.
How do I add back a view/table from a database to an existing diagram?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was afraid the update model from database option would change what I had done in the model, so I avoided it.
After hours of searching, I decided to try it and duh... it let me pick what I want to add.
Right click on your .edmx file and select Update Model From Database.  Check what you want and that's it.